# Aligning divs are side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm creating this interface for a travel website and I'm aligning two inputs side-by-side and they aren't aligning properly. I am most concerned with the Departure and Return inputs. The Return input and label are not aligning with the departure input and label.

Can someone checkout my code and suggest a solution. It's probably my vision, but if you can help me out, I'd appreciate it a bunch.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

#menu {
  background-color: black;
  clear: both;
}

#flights {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#flights:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

#hotels {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hotels:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

#cars {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#cars:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

#bundle {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bundle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

#flights-data {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  width: 180px;
  height: '';
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input#flight-departure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input#flight-return {
  display: inline;
  width: 48%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input#fly-from,
input#fly-to,
input#passengers {
  display: block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#depart-block {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
  width: 385px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#find-a-flight {
  width: 380px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#find-a-flight:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
}

label#return {
  margin: 0;
}

div.active#flights {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="active" id="flights">Flights</div>
    <div id="hotels">Hotels</div>
    <div id="cars">Cars</div>
    <div id="bundle">Bundle</div>
  </div>

  <div id="flights-data">
    <label for="fly-from">Flying from</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fly-from" value="Departure city or Airport">
    <label for="fly-to">Flying to</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fly-to" value="Departure city or Airport"><br>
    <div id="departing-block">
      <label for="Departure">Departing Flight</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="flight-departure" value="Pick-a-date">
      <label id="return" for="Return">Returning</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="flight-return" value="Pick-a-date">
    </div>
    <label for="passengers">Passengers</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="passengers" value="1 Adult 0 Children">
    <div id="find-a-flight">Find a Flight</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: dont use float for styling porpuse. It is not just out-dated but also never was the intended use. Float is only for floating images within a text paragraph. Either use `flexbox` or `css-grid` for layout designs

Comment: You have css called `#depart-block` but the id is `departing-block`. You probably also want a separate div for returning.

Comment: Is [that](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/mdraBba?editors=0100) the expected result?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to use grids. Since grids are relatively a new spec to css3, it will solve the problem and keep everything aligned properly. Thank you everyone who contributed to my question.

Comment: Louys-That's not the expected result. The divs should align horizontally.

Comment: The problem here is that the label has a display of block and should be inline. Once adjusted, both divs align properly.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following change in `<div id="flights-data">`:

```
    <label for="fly-from">Flying from</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fly-from" value="Departure city or Airport">
    <label for="fly-to">Flying to</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fly-to" value="Departure city or Airport"><br>
    <div id="departing-block">
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <label for="Departure">Departing Flight</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="flight-departure" value="Pick-a-date"> 
      </div>

      <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <label id="return" for="Return">Returning</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="flight-return" value="Pick-a-date">    
      </div>
      
     
    </div>
    <label for="passengers">Passengers</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="passengers" value="1 Adult 0 Children">
    <div id="find-a-flight">Find a Flight</div>
  </div>
```

this will align both the inputs side-by-side properly. I have checked it.